# zoom out firefox 52 on redhat 6.8 using selenium python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, redhat, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have redhat 6.8 where firefox is 52.8 esr and python is 3.4 and geckodriver is 18
My requirement is to zoom out the browser and take a screenshot of the required part of the webpage.

I tried below methods:

```
browser.execute_script("$('#values').css('zoom', 5);") ( This didnt work )
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '200%'") ( This is applicable only for chrome )

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "-")  ( This didnt work )
```

Below two methods I'm not getting appropriate results
    driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(0.8)";')
    driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin="3 4";')

Below worked on MAC with firefox 52.8, but not working on redhat 6.8 with firefox 52.8 geckodriver is 18

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('col-10')
location = element.location
size = element.size
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()  # saves screenshot of entire page
im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))  # uses PIL library to open image in memory
left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
im = im.crop((left, top, 2000, 2900))  # defines crop points
im.save('screen.png')
```

Note: Using firefox 52.8 esr because on redhat 6.8 we cannot upgrade to latest firefox and cant install chrome

Please help me to resolve the issue. I almost google search couldn't find an appropriate solution. Thanks in advance.